# Implement a binary hash like http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm

Tags: c#, .net

I have been struggling for 4 days trying to implement a hash algorithm in c# which works like the FIPS 198 standards document. I have reached a point where I have a value of

**06070405020300010e0f0c0d0a0b080976777475363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363653616d706c65202332**

I took this value and inserted it into the binary hash tool on http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm and the SHA-1 value is what I am expecting, but I can't replicate this in c#.

***Expected value:***

SHA-1: 74766e5f6913e8cb6f7f108a11298b15010c353a

When I use the SHA1 class in c# I get the value **a969fdc725114c8418ca5c23946bd09977054ff6**, which is the same as me entering my value above in the String Hash tool.

Could someone please point me in the right direction to generate what I require.

Comment: [Padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) probably explains this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to convert your hex-string data into a byte array. There are plenty of examples online of how to do this. One example posted to SO already is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/381588) (use the `StringToByteArray` function). Once you have a byte array, pass this through the SHA-1 hash and you should get the output you require.